# Word for "something used to bother or annoy someone by others"

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a word for something used to bother or annoy someone by others from time to time, like a threat by threatening to make known the secret which someone has shared with others.

Comment: You mean ‘blackmail’? Or specifically the thing you use in order to blackmail someone? I'm sure there is a word for that too, but I can't think of it right now. You'd often just say that you _have something on someone_.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet  Sounds like you've got the answer.  Why not post it as such, rather than as a comment?

Comment: Was this question set by a spammer by any chance? His avatar is "dead" so to speak :(

Comment: @Janus: Informally, the word you can't think of might be ***the dirt***.

Comment: @Mari, I thought the same. Question asked, then profile almost immediately deleted. Very odd.

Comment: @FumbleFingers More specifically 'Threatening to 'dish the dirt''.

Comment: It's strange that a threat can only "just bother or annoy someone". Perhaps, the threat is just something unimportant. If that's the case, how about *a thorn in one's side*?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you are thinking of the word "[incriminating](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/incriminating?showCookiePolicy=true)"?

> adjective - tending to suggest guilt   ⇒ Police searched his flat and found incriminating documents.

As you can see, it is an adjective, but can go in front of a noun like "[document](http://www.jta.org/1978/06/19/archive/mrs-slepak-signed-incriminating-document-under-severe-duress)" or "[photo](http://perezhilton.com/2013-10-07-justin-bieber-incriminating-photo-possible-marijuana-ariana-grande-instagram)" or "[evidence](http://law2.umkc.edu/faculty/projects/ftrials/simpson/evidence.html)".

Obviously it can refer to evidence suggesting guilt of a crime, but it can also be used in a broader sense. [Here](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/incriminate?show=0&t=1390081981) the verb is defined as

> to cause (someone) to appear guilty of or responsible for something (such as a crime)

So it need not be used only for guilt in a crime. I can't find a good example online, but one could say "He has a girlfriend, but I have an incriminating photo of him with another girl."

Note that Merriam Webster has the adjective form as "incriminatory". [Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=incriminating%20evidence,%20incriminatory%20evidence&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1;,incriminating%20evidence;,c0;.t1;,incriminatory%20evidence;,c0) shows that "incriminating evidence" has significantly more hits than "incriminatory evidence".

Answer (score 0):

I think the word or words you are looking for is **evidence** or **proof**. When we have the proof of someone's ill doing, we can use this to blackmail them.

**Evidence**: *The available body of facts or information indicating whether a belief or proposition is true or valid*

**Proof**: *Evidence or argument establishing or helping to establish a fact or the truth of a statement*

> My brother knows a secret about me **and has proof** and he is
>   blackmailing me. [<sup>1</sup>](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20120104045532AAcmcPU)